# Looking to have a property equal 0 unless another variable is on

Tags: python, drivers

So I've got a small project I'm working on, and I'm wondering if there's an expression I can use to get this result. I want this property to stay 0 unless two other properties are both 1, in which case this property can be either 0 or 1. But I'm not familiar with Python so I don't know how I'd write that.

Comment: You might be better off with a driver for something this simple. But without knowing more details it's impossible to help. What "property" are you needing? Scene? Object? Mesh? Custom property? Modifier property?..... the list goes on and on :)

Answer (score 1):

Add the variables to your driver, name them, and then check if they are equal to $1$ by using the equality operator: `==`

The way you describe combining both comparisons is the `and` (mathematically $∧$):

[image]

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`get`, `set` and `update` callbacks](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.props.html#bpy.props.BoolProperty).

```
import bpy


def set_value_c(self, value):
    self["value_c"] = value if self.value_a and self.value_b else False
    
def get_value_c(self):
    return self["value_c"]

def update_value_c(self, context):
    if self.value_c:
        if not self.value_a or not self.value_b:
            self.value_c = False

class MyPG(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):
    value_a: bpy.props.BoolProperty(update=update_value_c)
    value_b: bpy.props.BoolProperty(update=update_value_c)
    value_c: bpy.props.BoolProperty(set=set_value_c, get=get_value_c)
    

class HelloWorldPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_label = "Hello World Panel"
    bl_idname = "OBJECT_PT_hello"
    bl_space_type = 'PROPERTIES'
    bl_region_type = 'WINDOW'
    bl_context = "object"

    def draw(self, context):
        self.layout.prop(context.active_object.my_pg, "value_a")
        self.layout.prop(context.active_object.my_pg, "value_b")
        self.layout.prop(context.active_object.my_pg, "value_c")


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(MyPG)
    bpy.types.Object.my_pg = bpy.props.PointerProperty(type=MyPG)
    bpy.utils.register_class(HelloWorldPanel)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

[image]